# Categories as simplicial object in Set VS simplicial object in Cat

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

It is well known that any category allow for the construction of a functor from the simplex 1-category $\Delta_0$. All of the axioms of a category translate simply in the functoriality requirements.

This leads to an ordinary functor between 1-categories ($[~\_~,~=~]_0$ denoting the closed structure of $Cat_0$, the 1-category of categories and functors)

$N_0 : Cat_0 \to [\Delta_0^{op},Set]_0  $

$N_0(X)= \Delta_0^{op} \hookrightarrow Cat_0 \xrightarrow{[~\_~,~X]_0} Cat_0 \xrightarrow{U} Set$

However, it is also possible, and seems more natural in a way (as it captures more - for instance the fundamental adjunction $d_0 \dashv i \dashv d_1 $), to define a 2-functor between 2-categories

$N : Cat \to [\Delta^{op},Cat]  $

$N(X)= \Delta^{op} \hookrightarrow Cat \xrightarrow{[~\_~,~X]} Cat$

I am not too familiar with the simplicial approach.
Are there references which try to shy away from $N_0$ and use $N$? Is there some well known gain from doing so, like important construct which can't be done using $N_0$ which are possible using $N$ ?

Comment: The category of simplicial sets is a nice category and in some sense simpler than the 2-category of categories. On the other hand, the 2-category of simplicial categories is more complicated than the 2-category of categories. So why make things harder for yourself? Not to say there aren't uses for it – you may want to look up the notion of Rezk nerve.

Comment: thank you for the reference. I realized I really don't know much about this after reading Leinster's excellent post on how that embedding is in fact for algebras of a monad 
https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/01/mark_weber_on_nerves_of_catego.html